# Getting process's loaded modules which does not really exist

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, winapi

While examining Microsoft Word's loaded modules, I came across something very strange. I wrote a little program to output the location of all of the loaded DLLs. Here is the output:

[image: Loaded modules using snapshot's WinApi]

When I try to find these modules on my PC, I couldn't find them at the given location, but in another location:

[image: The DLL's actual location]

I couldn't figure out why the paths of the DLLs are different, and I couldn't find anything related to it in Google either, although I suspect it has something to do with the VFS thing.

That said, somehow Process Explorer manages to display the DLL's original location.

Can someone tell me how Process Explorer does that, and how I can achieve the same result in my code?

***--------------- EDIT ----------------***

1. I have also tried to inject a DLL and walk the LDR of WINWORD but still I can't see the original DLLs location.
2. Sysinternal's ListDlls utility doesn't show the original DLLs location also.
   As for now, only Process Explorer shows the right location.

Comment: @alk: If those were soft/hard links, they'd be user-visible.

Comment: @alk, These are not links.

Comment: `dumpbin /imports winword.exe` suggests that Office 2016 is using App-V

Comment: @theB, How does process explorer get the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office 2016 is using App-V to redirect and virtualize some of its paths. This complicates finding the DLLs a bit. Process Explorer is using a slightly more complicated<sup>1</sup> method for finding the DLLs. In general the process is:

1. Create a Tool Help 32 snapshot, with the `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` and `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` flags.
2. Use [`Module32First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684218.aspx) and [`Module32Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684221.aspx) to obtain information about the modules in the process.
3. To resolve symbolic links, which on my Office 2016 are present for the App-V dlls, open the file, and use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx) to obtain the resolved path. (Note this will be the path including the leading `\\?\` but that's easy enough to remove.)

An example implementation:

```
// Obtain the Process ID however you like. I used GetWindowThreadProcessId.
if (processId != 0)
{
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, processId);
    if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32W moduleInfo = { 0 };
        moduleInfo.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32W);

        BOOL ok = Module32FirstW(snapshot, &moduleInfo);
        if (!ok)
        {
            // The read failed, handle the error here.
        }
        do
        {
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(moduleInfo.szExePath, 
                                       0, 
                                       FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
                                       NULL, 
                                       OPEN_EXISTING, 
                                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                                       NULL);
            if (hFile)
            {
                WCHAR realPath[MAX_PATH];
                DWORD result = GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(hFile, 
                                                         realPath, 
                                                         MAX_PATH, 
                                                         FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    wcout << L"Module: " << realPath << endl;
                }

                CloseHandle(hFile);
            }
            else
            {
                wcout << L"Module Name: " << moduleInfo.szExePath << endl;
            }
        } while (Module32NextW(snapshot, &moduleInfo));

        CloseHandle(snapshot);
    }
}
```

*<sup>1</sup> Note that Process Explorer was written by Sysinternals, and may be using lower level information. This method does resolve the DLLs on my 2016 install.*

Comment: will it be available only within the visualized process or other processes will be able to call it as well?

Comment: I ran my test of that code in an independent scratch C++ conole application, without injecting a thread into the process. My install is a little different from yours, so there may be some unaccounted for edge cases, but it appears from experiments that Process Explorer is using this method, and all of the DLLs I get are physically present where reported.

Comment: Thank you dude. You really helped me

Comment: Unrelated, but I am kind of shocked that Office is now using App-V. I can't think of a good reason why, can you? Probably something to do with licensing... Remember when Office used to be a suite of useful apps for doing productivity work?

Comment: @CodyGray The only thing I can think of is that they're using App-V to abstract away the wierdness that comes from being both a store app and a shrinkwrap product. That said, I still think its a complicated solution to the problem. I'd have thought just adding a module loader that uses an appropriately altered DLL search path would be enough.

Comment: @theB, just tested your code and it did not manage to find those DLLs on 2016 office. Then I saw your side comment and realized you experienced the same issue. Do you know any possible way to overcome it?